# AVAudioRecorder and iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiorecorder, ios5.1

I have an app that records audio using AVAudioRecorder.  It works fine on devices running iOS versions prior to iOS 5.1, but with the latest release it does not increase the size of the audio recording file, which stays at a constant 4k.

```
// init audio recorder here so recording could be started immediately            
NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4],
                                AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                nil];           

// Get temp path name
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isDir = NO;
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
self.audioFilePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audio.ima4"];
NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.audioFilePath];
AVAudioRecorder *anAudioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioFileURL 
                                                               settings:recordSettings
                                                                  error:&error];
self.audioRecorder = anAudioRecorder;
[anAudioRecorder release];
 [self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
```

(wait a while, user presses record)
    [self.audioRecorder record];
(wait a while, 5-10 secs, user presses stop)
    [self.audioRecorder stop];

I've placed debug statements that inspect the temp file size and it is 4096 bytes throughout recording and only 4130 bytes after stop is called.

I don't see a way around this.  Is this a bug in iOS 5.1?